# Oj gem: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I'm trying to start up an application in localhost made it with Sinatra and after running `bundle install` I got the following error:

> /home/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/oj-2.14.6/lib/oj.rb:42:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/oj-2.14.6/lib/oj/oj.so (LoadError)

when I told rackup to start.

I already tried to uninstall the gem and re-install it. I also tried using the last version, but still got the same error.

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rack', '1.6.4'
gem 'sinatra', '1.4.5'
gem 'sinatra-advanced-routes', '0.5.3' ,:require => 'sinatra/advanced_routes'
gem 'rake', '10.5.0'
gem 'activerecord', '4.2.6'
gem 'activesupport', '4.2.6'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '2.0.9'
gem 'mysql2', '0.4.3'
gem 'unicorn', '5.0.1'
gem "typhoeus", '1.0.1'
gem 'i18n', '0.7.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '3.15.0.314'
gem 'oj', '2.14.6'
gem 'oj_mimic_json', '1.0.1'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.9.5'
gem 'sinatra-respond_to', '0.9.0'
gem 'shotgun', '~> 0.9.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed my ruby version to ruby 2.3.3 and works.